# Create an HTTP request after btoa() is complete in javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send a file as a base64 string to a server. The server requires that the data is sent as an HTTP 'POST' with the information is JSON. However, in my code, the request is sent before the string is converted. Please advise on what error I am making in my code.

This is the function which converts the file

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
var files = evt.files;
var file = files[0];
var string = '';
if (files && file) 
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(readerEvt)
    {
        var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
        string = btoa(binaryString);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
create_HTTP_request(string);};
```

This is my HTTP request function(s)

```
function create_HTTP_request(string)
{
 runTask('task_required_by_server', {'file' : string}, format_data);
 };



function runTask(task_name, inputs, callback){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                console.log('Request Successful!');
                callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
                console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
            else if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 500)
             {
                 console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
             }
            else {
                    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", '/api/v1/jobs', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({name: task_name, input: inputs}));
  };
```

I am new to Javascript. I basically want to call my create_HTTP_request function only after the btoa() function is complete. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can do that by moving the `create_HTTP_request(string)` call at the end of the `reader.onload` function.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I feel silly now... :)

Comment: You're wrong. The request is **not** sent before the string is converted! The request is sent before the file is read from disk. `btoa` is synchronous!

Comment: Ok. I think I understand what you mean. So, how do I make the request wait for btoa to finish its conversion?